# Mouse cursor disappearing (but still being captured) on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, mouse

Host: Mac OSX 10.9
Guest: Ubuntu 13.04
VirtualBox: 4.3.4 (just updated)

I'm having issues when I install guest additions (via device > add guest additions)

at the very beginning it tells me that it can't find the host kernel (with a message saying that if the installation of guest additions fails it may be because of this) - but then it seems to install the rest fine. the only issue is after I install guest additions and reboot my guest device, there seems to be an issue displaying my mouse.

The click works fine if I manage to navigate it over to where it should be - but I just can't see where my mouse is.

Any help? :|

Also, for some reason I'm unable to disable mouse integration (it's just greyed out under my Machine tab).

Comment: Not really an answer but I had this problem as well, I think it may be a bug in VB because my host was Ubuntu 12.04 and my guest was Ubuntu 12.04 as well.  I had to revert to VB 4.2 and then restore a snapshot of the guest to get it working again.  As far as the warning about the kernel, I get that just about every time I have tried to install guest additions but they installed fine. (Ubuntu 12.02 12.10, 13.04, 13.10) I had this(the mouse) issue in VB4.0 as well so maybe this is a regression for Mac that was only present in PCs(I have a Intel based PC)

Comment: Yeah Im guessing it's a bug then... Even after removing my guest additions the mouse issue persists so I had to recreate my VM again to get it to work. Who knows, but this is irksome

Comment: Yes, irksome.  I have the same problem recurring from time to time, same setup.   I haven't had to recreate the VM, but some combination of saving/restoring and rebooting the guest fixes it each time.